# How do you make your bot ignore reply mentions?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

In my bot, I have an event for replying to when the bot is mentioned. The issue is, that it replies when u mention the bot through replying to it. How can I fix this? Here's my code:

```py
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_message(self, msg):

    guild = msg.guild

    prefix = get_prefix(self.client, guild)

    if msg.author == self.client.user:
        
        return
    
    if msg.mention_everyone:
        
        return

    if self.client.user.mentioned_in(msg):

        embed = discord.Embed(description=f"The prefix for this server is `{prefix}`   <:info:857962218150953000>", color=0x505050)

        await msg.channel.send(embed=embed)
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```py
if self.client.user.mentioned_in(msg):
```

to

```py
if msg.guild.me.mention in msg.content:
```

#### Why this happens

discord messages use a special field in it's messages to specify if someone is mentioned or not, if a message has someone in that field then the message will ping that someone. mentioned_in works that way so you can figure out if a certain message pings a certain person. when we use the msg.guild.mention part, we manually check for the mention instead of discord telling us if someone was mentioned since discord counts replies as mentions

Comment: I tried doing this, but it still replies to when I reply to the bot with reply mention on.

Comment: Well then your code is probably in the wrong place, because when I tried it worked fine for me. You can also try what Taufeeq Riyaz suggested which achieves the same thing but in a difference way

Answer (score 0):

I've used the following code for similar applications.
Note - Replace 'client' in `client.user.id` with what you've used like `bot.user.id`

````
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content in [f'<@{client.user.id}', f'<@!{client.user.id}>']:
        await message.channel.send("Hey! My prefix is ```,```")

    await client.process_commands(message)
````